# Ajax from local file to server

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-407

I'm creating a HTML/JS file for people to enter details on a tablet, which get stored in localStorage, and then later on they will be uploaded to a web server via ajax. The storage part is working fine, however, every/any ajax post I make, valid URL, link to an image, made up url all return with 407 error.

Is this a common issue or is this something to do with my works proxy settings?

I don't have the tablet at the moment to test on so I can only test on my work PC.

Comment: Only your work proxy knows for sure.

Comment: For some reason it's decided to start working now so it does seem it was a proxy issue.